# Background on Agda Categories library?

Tags: agda, category-theory

I'm trying to understand the Categories library, but I'm fairly new to Agda, so I'm looking for some sort of document explaining the choices that were made in the implementation of the library. There's a link to such a thing in the readme, but it's broken.

Comment: Which categories library?  [There are several].  If you mean https://github.com/copumpkin/categories, then I heartily agree with your request!

Comment: Yes, I did mean that one. But if you can recommend another that comes with more explanation, I'd be interested in that, too!

Comment: That's the one I use.  It seems extremely well designed, but I have had to reverse engineer a lot of that design while using/extending it.

Comment: @JacquesCarette Archive.org archived some (but maybe not all) of the pages from 2010: http://web.archive.org/web/20100225215628/http://web.student.chalmers.se/~stevan/ctfp/html/README.html

Comment: Maybe @copumpkin (https://stackoverflow.com/users/104136/copumpkin) knows the answer :) [I thought I could use this to notify the user but apparently comments don't work that way]

Comment: Hi, have you found anything around this subject ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For people landing here in the future: the 'new' [agda-categories](https://github.com/agda/agda-categories) has some documentation in its readme about the choices, and also there is a [published paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.07059) about it that goes into a lot more details regarding the design choices.